# Safari trigger pop state twice and when page load

Tags: javascript

```
  $(function ($) {
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
                var hashLocation = location.hash;
                var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
                var hashName = hashSplit[1];
                if (hashName !== '') {
                    var hash = window.location.hash;
                    if (hash === '') {                    
                            var agree = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
                            if (agree) {
                                'do something
                            } else {
                                'do something
                            }
                        }       
                }
            });
            window.history.pushState('forward', null, './Payment.aspx');
        }
```

> I would like to call the webmethod when user click browser's back button. These code working fine at all other browser except on Safari 5.1.7. The confirmation message should popup when user click browser back button but now popup when page load. Is it possible for me to used the current code to achieve this?